# TypeError("'AssetId' is an invalid keyword argument for Assets")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I have no clue what I did wrong as it was working completely fine earlier, I haven't changed anything within the code but the error 'TypeError("'AssetId' is an invalid keyword argument for Assets")' keeps popping up? My goal is to basically successfully add an asset. please help!

```
@route('/newasset', method = 'post')
def newasset():
db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db/MusicAssets.db')
#dynamic class creation - creates a sessionmaker class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
session = Session()
new_assetid = request.forms.get('AssetId')
new_assetname = request.forms.get('AssetName')
new_category = request.forms.get('Category')
new_status= request.forms.get('Status')
new_borrower = request.forms.get('Borrower')
new_value = request.forms.get('Value')

new_asset = Assets(
    AssetId = new_assetid,
    AssetName = new_assetname,
    Category = new_category,
    Status = new_status,
    Borrower = new_borrower,
    Value = new_value
    )

    session.add(new_asset)
    session.commit()
    return template('success.tpl', message = 'Asset added')
```

Comment: What is `Assets`? Is it a user defined class or something you're importing from a library?

Comment: Assets is a database table. I’m getting my information from the database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We don't have enough information to help you yet. Adding the complete stack trace to your question might help.